# Raspberry Pi Raspbian Mono Program Shutoff

Tags: mono, raspberry-pi

I am currently running a VB application through mono on Raspbian. After a bit of troubleshooting the program boots and appears to be running quite well. However if left to itself for a few minutes the VB application just shuts off. This program runs excellently on the windows pc for any duration. Barring this being an issue with the VB code itself is there any major PI related issues that I may have missed in setting up mono? I set up mono the usual way and am launching via "sudo mono app.exe" in terminal.

Thank you for any insight you may provide into this!

UPDATE: mono just FINALLY threw out an errot to me System.OutOfMemoryException : Not enough memory to complete operation [GDI+ status: out of memory]

UPDATE2: Memory leak, its a code related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to anyone else that runs into this issue. For us it was a memory leak.